# Insert html tag in contenteditable div and set cursor in it

Tags: javascript, range, contenteditable

I have following Javascript code which works in FireFox correctly but not in Google Chrome.
This function inserts html tag in editable DIV and it should keep cursor in it so that user can see the text having style applied to SPAN and class.
Following code is works in FF but not Chrome

```
function insertTextAtCursor(text, myid) { 

    if(myid != "")
    {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.setAttribute('class', 'mystyle');
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);        
        span.innerHTML=text;
         
        range.deleteContents();        
        range.insertNode(span); 
        
        range.setStart(span, 0);
        range.setEnd(span, 0);

        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    
    }
   
}
```

Any change is required for Google Chrome for it to work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is working in chrome .before call the function should select the text in the div and div should not blank

Comment: I will create a demo and will share a link.

Comment: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/silkograph/insertHTML/blob/master/auto-link.html check the demo in FF and Chrome. Text becomes red in FF but not in Chrome.

Comment: It redirect some where else , Before call the function select some code in the div .If no selection that is null reference error is comming